# How to add a pre-made template to products

Tags: html, magento, templates, html-table

I have an eBay shop and when I make a listing I have a pre made template and I just import information to this template.

I have a short description, features, and specifications. And I need to add automatically `<li></li>` to every line and a pre made HTML table with custom style, Which will know how to separate with "/" symbol like I have in my private listing tool.

Is this even possible? And if it is any idea how?

Comment: magento didn't work like this way. You need to do customization for this

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe Magento works in that manner however there is an easy efficient way to accomplish this manually.

Try putting the code in Sumblime text 3 with teh Emmet plugin.
From there you can type a command like `ul>li*8` (the 8 is the # of items or `<li></li>` tags) and then press the `tab` key.

the results will be

```
<ul>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
</ul>
```

From there you can fill in the blanks between the `<li></li>`.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do it this way because I'm importing a lot of products trough excel spreadsheet and this way I won't be able to bulk import. Anyway good idea tho.

Comment: How many products are you importing? I ask so that i might be able to help you with a solution to fit your needs.